# Remove header from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase, android-titlebar

I am using firebase UI android library and my main activity inherits from FirebaseLoginBaseActivity.

For some odd reason a title bar was added to my main view which I don't know how to get rid of since it does not appear in my layout xml.

When trying this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
```

In the onCreate it fails with this message:

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called
>   before adding content

When trying to set this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml it fails with this message:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Are you sure that is the `onCreate()` method which causes the exception?

Comment: Put your `requestWindowFeature` before the `super()` and see if that works. Maybe `FirebaseLoginBaseActivity` loads content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting your base theme to `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` instead of `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Add this style to your **styles.xml** if it doesn't already exists :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

and in your **v21/styles.xml** :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

and set the style this way

```
android:theme="@android:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to hide the titlebar, try to put this after setContentView function:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```